# Answering a question you previously voted to close

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, editing, etiquette

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/205507/) was recently posted, asking very ambiguously about the Windows 7 SP1 RC. I voted to close it as "not a real question", since it was just asking for comments on whether anybody had tried it out and "what they thought". At the time that I voted to close, I posted a comment pointing out that no real question had been asked, and that it would likely be closed *unless it were edited to have a real question* about SP1. The question was then edited, first a non-helpful edit by the original poster but then an edit by another user which turned it into a valid question. By the time this edit had occurred, the question had 4 close votes, but I figured since it had been edited to the point of being a real question, it would be worth answering since I had relevant information.

So here is my question then. Is it appropriate to answer a question which I previously voted to close, given that I feel it's been edited to the point of being an acceptable question? There's no way to retract a close-vote, or else I would have. The question was subsequently closed shortly after I answered, but not before the answer had been accepted. What is the appropriate protocol in a situation like this? I don't want to be seen as rep-whoring by posting an answer on a question I initially voted to close, but I also feel like it's reasonable to post an answer when a question has been edited to the point of being valid. Did I act reasonably in this situation, and in the future, how should I approach questions like this?

Furthermore, with this question specifically, I feel like it's now a good enough question that it might deserve re-opening, however a diamond mod cast the final close vote, so is there a reason I'm overlooking for why it is still a bad question? Is it due to SP1 being RC, or is the question itself still not within SuperUser's guidelines? I feel like it probably is.

Comment: I closed it because it was a discussion. Nothing more. Nothing less. No matter how it was asked.

Comment: Note that we have had the ability to retract close vote for a while — apparently, since July 15, 2013.  That's when the pink tag on [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/195817) was changed from [meta-tag:status-planned] to [meta-tag:status-completed], according to the revision history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you feel it has been edited into a real question, then go ahead and answer it.

The same applies to duplicates that turn out to have a slight twist, where a distinction has been added later on.

However, I vote against answering **until** a question is worth answering!